# I want to give 20% discount when someone buy more then 500 dollars

Tags: php, html

I'm a new student in PHP. I want to give 20% discount when someone buy more then 100 Dollars.

Here is my current code that shows unique item price and total price including VAT.

HTML:

```
<form action="sweet1.php" method="post">
Item Name: <input type="text" value="" style="display: none;">
    <select name="sweet">
        <option value="Item one@250">Item One USD 250</option>
        <option value="Item Two@180">Item Two USD 180</option>
    </select>

<br><br>

Quantity: <input type="text" name="qty" value="">

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Purchase">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$sweet_name=$_POST['sweet'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];

$position=strpos($sweet_name, '@');
echo $position;
$sweet=substr($sweet_name,0,$position);
$price=substr($sweet_name,$position+1);

echo 'Sweet Details';
echo '<br>Item Name: '.$sweet;
echo '<br>Qty: '.$qty;
echo '<br>Unique Item Price: '.$price;
echo '<br>Total Iteam Price: '.$price*$qty;
$tprice=$price*$qty;
$vat= $tprice*.10;
$tamount=$tprice+$vat;
echo '<br> Total Amount (VAT Included): '.$tamount;
?>
```

Comment: calculate 20% of  `$tprice` like you did in `$vat` and deduct amount from total amount

Comment: There are a lot of issues you are going to encounter with this. To start a user can modify the price by changing the value in the DOM and then they pay `0`. You need to validate the values.

Comment: @sumonst21.. you may try below code once to avoid DOM related changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below code to avoid DOM changes also.

```
<form action="sweet1.php" method="post">
    Item Name: <input type="text" value="" style="display: none;">
    <select name="sweet">
        <option value="item_1">Item One USD 250</option>
        <option value="item_2">Item Two USD 180</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>
    Quantity: <input type="text" name="qty" value="">

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Purchase">
</form>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$sweet_arr = array(
    "item_1" => array(
        "name" => "Item one@250",
        "price" => "250"
    ),
    "item_2" => array(
        "name" => "Item Two@180",
        "price" => "180"
    )
);
$sweet_name = $_POST['sweet'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];

try {

    if (!is_array($sweet_arr[$sweet_name])) {
        throw new Exception("Item not found.");
    }

    $sweet = $sweet_arr[$sweet_name]['name'];
    $price = $sweet_arr[$sweet_name]['price'];

    if (empty($price)) {
        throw new Exception("Price not defined.");
    }

    echo 'Sweet Details';
    echo '<br>Item Name: ' . $sweet;
    echo '<br>Qty: ' . $qty;
    echo '<br>Unique Item Price: ' . $price;
    echo '<br>Total Iteam Price: ' . $price * $qty;

    $tprice = $price * $qty;
    $vat = $tprice * .10;
    if ($tprice > 500) {
        $discount = $tprice * .20;
        $tprice -= $discount;
    }
    $tamount = $tprice + $vat;

    echo '<br> Total Amount (VAT Included): ' . $tamount;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Simhachalam Gulla sir thank u very much for your good answer but actually I can't find why it showing "Price not defined." when i try to submit. can plz clear me about that?

Comment: Sorry for that..Please take new code..I missed the condition for `throw new Exception("Price not defined.");`

Comment: Welcome :).. please do vote it will be useful for others too.. thanks in advance

Comment: Sir, One more extra request for you, if you have little free time then please write some more codes related with this subject that will help us to get some more features and actually I have class today and it was my homework so I want to give surprise to my teacher. (but please do not think it's important, but will be grateful.) thank you very much again :)

Comment: Yeah sure... Feel free to ask me any time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sweet_name=$_POST['sweet'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];

$position=strpos($sweet_name, '@');
echo $position;
$sweet=substr($sweet_name,0,$position);
$price=substr($sweet_name,$position+1);

echo 'Sweet Details';
echo '<br>Item Name: '.$sweet;
echo '<br>Qty: '.$qty;
echo '<br>Unique Item Price: '.$price;
echo '<br>Total Iteam Price: '.$price*$qty;
$tprice=$price*$qty;
$vat= $tprice*.10;
$tamount=$tprice+$vat;
$discount = 0;
if ($tprice > 500) {
  $discount = $tprice * 20/100;
}
$tamount -= $discount;
echo '<br> Total Amount (VAT Included): '.$tamount;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to give 20% if some one buys for $500 on total amount then add the below code

```
    if ($tamount > 500)
    {
    $discount = $tamount*20/100;
    $tamount = $tamount - $discount;
    }
```

Comment: Sailesh Chowdary Doppalapudi Sir thank you very much for you answer, it will work but just for confirming I want to give 20% discount if someone buys more than $500. like: buys: $500 get 20% discount and buys $550 to more get 20% discount. 

also can u please answer if I want to give discount on items same as amount like buy more then 20 items to get 20% discount. thanks in advance for this. @sailesh-chowdary-doppalapudi